# What the logic behind b1 ? b1 : b2 in my coding in if-conditions?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

1.Here is the assignment.

Declare a function or that works like ||, but without using the || operator. /**

1. @param {any} ??? - the first operand
2. @param {any} ??? - the second operand
3. @returns {any} the same result as applying the || operator to the given operands, in order

2.Here is what tried(actually people gave me advice on **return b1 ? b1 : b2**.But i couldn't understand it ,and haven't found a proper explanation about it online.

```
function or(b1, b2) {
  if (b1 == false && b2 == false) return false;
  else return b1 ? b1 : b2;
}
```

3.Here are the coding tests, and the code above passed all of them. But would anyone tell me the logic of **b1 ? b1 : b2**. I am a beginner, please help me !

**//TEST 1**

```
actual = or("bananas", false);

expected = "bananas";

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.log("    actual: ", actual);
  console.log("  expected: ", expected);
}
```

**//TEST 2**

```
actual = or("", "bananas");

expected = "bananas";

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.log("    actual: ", actual);
  console.log("  expected: ", expected);
}
```

**//TEST 3**

```
actual = or(true, true);

expected = true;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.log("    actual: ", actual);
  console.log("  expected: ", expected);
}
```

**//TEST 4**

```
actual = or(true, false);

expected = true;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Yay! Test PASSED.");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.log("    actual: ", actual);
  console.log("  expected: ", expected);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function or(b1, b2) {
  if (b1 == false && b2 == false) return false;
  else return b1 ? b1 : b2;
}
```

Multiple things are happing Headers. Here, You have a test function with `falsy` check. Falsy is validateNumber, it can be null, blank string or zero. The condition will always return false. If you really looking to test value with the type you should use === instead.

```
console.log(Boolean("")) //false
console.log(Boolean(null))//false

console.log(Boolean(0))//false

console.log(Boolean(" "))//true
console.log(Boolean("1"))//true
```

Comment: @xdeepaky to change the way to below, but "false"  is showed as an output(not bananas as expected) , which couldn't pass the first test.

if(b1 === true)
 return b1;
else 
 return b2

Answer (score 1):

> b1 ? b1 : b2

This means that if b1 is true/valid it will simply returns the result due to code of b1 otherwise it will simply return the result due to code of b2

Answer (score 1):

`b1 ? b1 : b2` is using a [Ternary Operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

If you were to write it as a if-else statement it would look like

```
if (b1 === true) {
  return b1;
} else {
  return b2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `or` function like this.

```
function or(b1, b2) {
  if (b1) return b1;
  if (b2) return b2;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`b1 ? b1: b2`  is using Ternary Operation

In simple words it can be interpreted as

```
   condition ? (statement when condition is True) : (statement when condition is false)
```

Since it is using `three operands` , hence called Ternary(three) Operation.

So, `b1 ? b1: b2`  means if `b1` is true, then return `b1` else return `b2`.

You can also break it to `if else` statement like this:

```
if(b1 === true)
 return b1;
else 
 return b2;
```

Comment: *... when condition is [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)!* not `true`. Using `"bananas" || "apples"` and `"bananas" ? "bananas" : "apples"` will both resolve to `"bananas"`, but `"bananas" !== true`.

Comment: @Thomas, thank you so much, I've got to be aware of "truthy" concept.

Comment: @Thomas Could you please give me some advice that what's going on if "bananas" ? "bananas" : false, returning false as a result in console.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Example to help you to understand the **Conditional (ternary) operator** in JavaScript, and so about `b1 ? b1 : b2`.

```
function whatUserTyped(str) {
    let b1 = str;
    let b2 = '-Nothing-';

    if (b1) {
        return b1;
    } else {
        return b2;
    }
}

function whatUserTypedButConditionalOperator(str) {
    let b1 = str;
    let b2 = '-Nothing-';

    let rst = b1 ? b1 : b2;

    return rst;
}

let str1 = 'hahaha'; //User typed 'hahaha' into a input[type=text] or textarea or whatever;
let str2 = ''; //Empty string value. User left the input or textarea empty.

console.log('You said ' + whatUserTyped(str1)); //'You said hahaha'
console.log('You said ' + whatUserTyped(str2)); //'You said -Nothing-'

console.log('You said ' + whatUserTypedButConditionalOperator(str1)); //'You said hahaha'
console.log('You said ' + whatUserTypedButConditionalOperator(str2)); //'You said -Nothing-'
```

The **Conditional (ternary) operator** is **condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse**. It's a form of syntactic sugar for `if...else` statement.

Well the `b1 ? b1 : b2` is very tricky. Most of times if the b1 is falsy, it's not recommended to return another str/obj or whatever instantly.

Most time it is used like this: `a ? b : c`

```
function isBob(thatGuy) {
    let a;

    if (thatGuy === 'Bob') {
        a = true;
    } else {
        a = false;
    }

    b = 'That Guy is Bob';
    c = 'That Guy is not Bob';

    return (a ?  b : c);
}

console.log(isBob('Bob')); //That Guy is Bob
console.log(isBob('Jimmy')); //That Guy is not Bob
```

The `a` is considered as Boolean and most time `a` is **Truthy**, because in JavaScript, **All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN)**, thus the tricky `b1 ? b1 : b2` is not very suitable.

References:

- [MDN - Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [MDN - Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [MDN - Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation.It's appreciated!